# Python string of numbers to date

Tags: python, pandas

I have am trying to process data with a timestamp field. The timestamp looks like this:

'20151229180504511' (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)

and is a python string. I am attempting to convert it to a python datetime object. Here is what I have tried (using pandas):

```
data['TIMESTAMP'] = data['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,"%Y%b%d%H%M%S"))

# returns error time data '20151229180504511' does not match format '%Y%b%d%H%M%S'
```

So I add milliseconds:

```
data['TIMESTAMP'] = data['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,"%Y%b%d%H%M%S%f")) 
# also tried with .%f all result in a format error
```

So tried using the dateutil.parser:

```
data['TIMESTAMP'] = data['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda s: dateutil.parser.parse(s).strftime(DateFormat)) 
# results in OverflowError: 'signed integer is greater than maximum'
```

Also tried converting these entries using the pandas function:

```
data['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TIMESTAMP'], unit='ms', errors='coerce') 
# coerce does not show entries as NaT
```

I've made sure that whitespace is gone. Converting to Strings, to integers and floats. No luck so far - pretty stuck.

Any ideas?

p.s. Background info: The data is generated in an Android app as a the java.util.Calendar class, then converted to a string in Java, written to a csv and then sent to the python server where I read it in using pandas `read_csv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try :
`datetime.strptime(x,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")`

You miss this :

- **%b** : Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
- **%m** : Month as a zero-padded decimal number.

Comment: Might be worth highlighting that the key difference here is the use of `%m` for the month (Month as a zero-padded decimal number) instead of `%b` (Month as locale’s abbreviated name)

Comment: *Groan*. Yes it was that. Just when I'd convinced myself this wasn't a stupid question. Oh well, will leave it there for the next lost datetimer.

Answer (score 3):

[`%b`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) is for locale-based month name abbreviations like `Jan`, `Feb`, etc.
Use `%m` for 2-digit months:

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':['20151229180504511','20151229180504511']})

In [37]: df
Out[37]: 
           Timestamp
0  20151229180504511
1  20151229180504511

In [38]: pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
Out[38]: 
0   2015-12-29 18:05:04.511
1   2015-12-29 18:05:04.511
Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```